# Need a way to copy SharePoint Document Library to dynamics 365

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, dynamics-365

I have a requirement to copy the SharePoint document library to dynamics 365 against any entity.
Suppose I created a new opportunity and added a file in it's note. Therefore I need a flow that copy that document library to my dynamics 365.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Instead of creating your custom document management solution couldn't you just use the out of the box document management SharePoint integration feature? When you use that feature it is actually enable by default for the opportunity entity as well. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/integration-dev/integrate-sharepoint?view=op-9-1

Comment: appreciated but it's the requirement I need to use flow

Comment: In that case can you clarify what you mean by the requirement 'copy that document library to my dynamics 365'? Do you mean you need to copy a document link to the timeline of a specific Opportunity id record?

Comment: Yes that the one I'm looking for